# Sugarcrm copy a table to another database table by batch (cronjob)

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I have some issues with sugarcrm.
As you know that sugarcrm table, they do have ID (which is a unique string), they not run by sequential. e.g

> 4bab37e4-798a-e01c-75de-4e4397f358b7

For example, I would like to copy the table `sugarcrm.accounts` to `something.accounts`, in `something.accounts` I added some custom file on it for another PHP process usage.

Now the problem is, my sugarcrm table got huge records there, I plan to run it batch by batch, each time I would like to copy 10,000 records to my `somthing.accounts`.

However, `sugarcrm.accounts`, their ID, not in sequential, how do I know offset parameter?

I do not want to amend sugarcrm table / or add a temporary table in sugarcrm. (e.g `sugarcrm.account_index`), it might caused me having problem to do the upgrade.

So anyone have any idea, how do I get the index number? Is MySQL got hidden index?

Or anyone have better idea to do the database table copy another database table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is the following:
 - Select all rows from `sugarcrm.accounts` and order by date_created ascending.
 - Use limit to only select a subset of the rows (store the offset from batch to batch)
 - Copy the subset of rows to `something.accounts`

If new records are added later they will still be copied, since they will be last in the set. However, if you delete records in `sugarcrm.accounts` while running the batch jobs, then you need to change the offset as well, since you might omit some rows.

Another way, if the two databases/tables are in the same MySQL instance, is to join the two tables, and select the next 10.000 which doesn't exist in `something.accounts`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The problem with order by `date_created` also not unique. It is because some data is using import function, the `date_created` not a unique value. It might have few hundred with same value.

I guess I might consider your 2nd suggestion. That's should be workable. 

You have any idea to deal with huge database like this?

Comment: Another option, I guess, is to manually add an custom ID column to the `sugarcrm.accounts` table with autoincrement. That way you should be able to easily copy data using offset and limit. And it won't kill sugar.